# Upload files on Google drive using Python API without browser activity

Tags: python, django, google-drive-api

I am working on Google Drive API to upload the video and then get the URL of that video.

Here is the code I tried to upload the files:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
# Now build our api object, thing
drive_api = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'Test file',
    # 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
}
media = MediaFileUpload('/path/to/file',
                        mimetype='text/text',
                        resumable=True)
file = drive_api.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
```

My end goal is to upload files on Google Drive via some scheduler on the server.

I also tried [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/gsuite-apis-intro/#0) to upload the files.

But the above code and the tutorial always opens the browser and get permission. I want to upload files without a browser activity.

How can I upload files without the browser activity like only using `api_key` or `client_id` etc?

Comment: Are you using a G Suite domain or a gmail account?

Comment: I am using Gmail account

Comment: Can you not authorise your application locally then just copy over your `token.pickle` file?

Comment: I am able to get `token.pickle` file but how can I use it?

Comment: It needs to be placed in the working directory of your python code which uses the API. Use SFTP or SSH to copy it over if it's a remote server.